# Surf rock instrumental jam - possibly the Ventures?

Tags: identify-this-song, instrumental

https://vocaroo.com/i/s0B7MIMoh4ma

I've been looking out for this for years, I think it might be a jam of [The Ventures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ventures)...

Update: The name of the song is [Ravin' Blue](https://youtu.be/82VW_7P_MpE), it's not as famous as I thought it was...

Answer (score 2):

As per the original poster, this is indeed an instrumental by the Ventures. It is called [Ravin' Blue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82VW_7P_MpE&feature=youtu.be) and it appeared on their *House of the Rising Sun* album.

Answer (score -2):

It's called ["Wipeout"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p13yZAjhU0M&feature=youtu.be) it's a surfing song

Comment: No, that's not the same song